# Convert html2pdf with toc, color and unicode support?

Tags: pdf, conversion, html, sphinx, pandoc

Is there a way I can convert large html file (produced with sphinx by the way) to pdf with color, table of contents (toc) and unicode support?

There's `htmldoc` -- but it neither support color, nor unicode.

There's `rst2pdf` sphinx plugin -- but currently it breaks math rendering, and also can't word-warp code lines.

There's a way to export to `xetex` in `sphinx` -- but it can't word-wrap code-blocks, and also don't support `svg` images.

**Edit**:

I tried to use `pandoc`:

```
pandoc index.html --mathjax --toc -o index.pdf
```

it gives:

```
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source.
! LaTeX Error: Command \guillemotright unavailable in encoding OT1.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.55   2012-Sep-11} »
```

I'm stucked...

Comment: Edit your LaTeX code, and add this line at the beginning: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
`

Comment: But it won't wrap code. In latex you can only wrap code it you're using `listings`. But I have code colored by pygments -- and in listings I can't get it parse that coloring... So You see -- I worked in this way -- latex doesn't work really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/)? It's based on WebKit, and has CSS support, of course with colors.

<strike>It doesn't have TOC support</strike>, err, i guess it does.

It's basically rendering to PDF.

Comment: Versions 0.10.0 and above does have a toc support: `wkhtmltopdf toc my.html my.pdf`. I see that the firefox extension I tried uses exactly this lib.

Comment: @Adobe cool, I may have used an older version that didn't have TOC, i hope this works for you.

Comment: Well currently I'm trying to figure out how to set width of the content. Despite toc has correct width my body is not. Perhaps it is set somewhere in my css...

Comment: Yep, solved it with `body {
    width: 150%;
}` addition to css. The command I use: `./wkhtmltopdf-0.10.0-amd64 --enable-javascript --javascript-delay 5000 --no-stop-slow-scripts --no-background  toc index.html 1.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

If you are on linux or Mac, you can try `html2pdf` or `html2ps foo.html; ps2pdf foo.ps`. Neither of these methods is perfect but they might work.

You can also try opening the file in an office suite and export to pdf. I know that both word and libreoffice support this. This is the only option I know of if you are using windows.

The best way would be to export the file as TeX or LaTeX and compile the pdf, you can edit the LaTeX code to fix any wrapping issues. You can also easily convert your images to png using `convert` from ImageMagick:

```
$ mogrify -format png *.svg
```

Comment: LibreOffice deforms images and doesn't render math. LaTeX doesn't support UTF and can't wrap code (as I point in the question).

Comment: @Adobe, LaTeX [does](http://vemod.net/how-to-use-utf-8-encoding-with-latex) support utf8. I don't know what environment LaTeX uses for your code blocks but you should be able to mke them wrap with a minimum of editing. You haven't said what OS you are using, on Linux at least, you can "print to pdf" instead of a printer so you could do it directly from your browser.

Comment: But is there a way I can get a pdf with toc -- when printing to pdf? I'm using Kubuntu linux, but I can go for any OS if -- there's a solution. Sphinx uses Verbatim LaTeX environment in code blocks and these are absolutely impossible to word-wrap.

Comment: It depends on how your toc is set up. Does latex give you a toc? As for code blocks, you can replace verbatim with a simple float and change the font inside the float. Getting beyond the scope of your question though. Try printing the html doc and choosing "print to pdf" as the printer.

Comment: My index.html doesn't have a toc (it can't have one -- because there's no pages). I want to get a book with toc out of single large html file. Simpe print to pdf won't produce no toc.

Answer (score 0):

[Print pages to pdf](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/print-pages-to-pdf/) firefox addon does make a toc.